# Does nextjs and vercel cache SSR pages which are user filter and search?

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I know nextjs but have never done a project like this, it is a SSR catalog, and using firebase for the backend, but as the filter and full text search are client side, I encounter with this question: if a thousand of people make filtering and full text search... that will lead to a thousand hits into firebase? or if the URL is the same will it be returned by cache?

thanks for reading